# Adding Data Sets with Parameters to a sub report causes the sub report to error out in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Reporting Services Report that runs fine with a sub report as long as the data sets inside the sub report uses filters instead of query parameters.

The problem with this is that it seems to be pulling the entire data set and then filtering it which is a performance nightmare.

The solution that I thought would be the simplest was to simply add query parameters to the sub reports data sets and have them set equal to the value of the report parameters that the sub report contains.

When I run the report after adding the parameters to the sub report the sub report will no longer run. As soon as I remove the query parameters from the sub report data sets it runs fine.

Is there something special one must do to use query parameters in the sub report data sets?

The stack trace in the logs seems to indicate that the CONSTRAINED constraint on the strtoset functions in the generated MDX are being violated. I'm not sure what that means though. When I try and removed the constrained manually from the mdx (including the comma) it won't even consider it valid MDX.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check out this link maybe this will help http://ch1n2.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/the-restrictions-imposed-by-the-constrained-flag-in-the-strtoset-function-were-violated/

Comment: do you have multivalued parameters that are being passed?

Comment: @BhupeshC No sir. The parameters that are being passed in are coming from each data row in a tablix that iterates over account holders. That might explain the constrained violation.

Comment: if thats a dimension value, then it actually is stored as `[Dim Something].[Something].&[Value]` in the cube. While passing, if you send only `Value`, the issue may occur. Try passing in the specified format `[Dim Something].[Something].&[Value]` and check

Comment: @BhupeshC I will try that using string concatenation on the main report. Is there an easier way than string concatenating that you know of? Also Thanks for the help I think this is putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the value expression of the subreport parameter `="[Dim Something].[Something].&[" & Fields!Field1.Value & "]`

concatenation operator - > &

Comment: Thank you so much @BhupeshC ! It took a senpai like you to help me see that my thinking about the problem had become too narrow minded. The  report looks great now!